# Join two tables with one table

Tags: sql, join

I need to do the following (I am not really sure if it is possible to do using SQL)

### Table A

col_a_1, col_a_2, col_a_3

### Table B

col_a_1, col_b_1, col_b_2....

### Table C

col_a_1, col_c_1, col_c_2....

were col_a_1 is unique in table A. I need to join tables A, B, C such that every entry in table A will appear multiple times but every entry in table B and C appears only once and against the same col_a_1 of table A.

I know how to do it using the code. Is it also possible to do with SQL alone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: This is a pretty good resource. I'll sure check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either want to use an outer join of some sort. either left or full outer.

```
SELECT A.*, B.*, C.* 
FROM Table_A A
LEFT JOIN Table_B B on A.col_A_1 = B.Col_A_1
LEFT JOIN table_C C on A.Col_A_1 = C.Col_A_1


SELECT A.*, B.*, C.* 
FROM Table_A A
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B B on A.col_A_1 = B.Col_A_1
FULL OUTER JOIN table_C C on A.Col_A_1 = C.Col_A_1
```

or possibly a union result... just depends on what you're after.

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM Table_A A
INNER JOIN Table_B B on A.col_A_1 = B.Col_A_1
UNION
SELECT A.*, C.* 
FROM Table_A A
INNER JOIN Table_C C on A.col_A_1 = C.Col_A_1
```

Comment: It was the second one (Full outer join). Thank you so much for the help. Also, thanks for the link.